# "MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete" error on webapi upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I receive only on certain files an error when uploading to a webapi controller.

The error is "MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete"

It seems the error is linked to some kind of not well terminated POST data but as I inspect the parameters sent from the browser with firebug everything seems ok.

[This post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1777847.aspx/1?MVC4%20Beta%20Web%20API%20and%20multipart%20form%20data) propose a workaround that doesn't work for me. I have looked also at [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/html-forms-and-multipart-mime)

I am utilizing the MultipartFormDataStreamProvider for deserialization.

Here a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sw9foaca1skkl5r/M5Q7BJwGxw) to two similar pdf documents, one working and one not.
I included also the zip of another sample html5 webapi upload application coming from [strathweb.com](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/04/html5-drag-and-drop-asynchronous-multi-file-upload-with-asp-net-webapi/).
The application will work with one doc and not the other.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible code or does it just happen only occasionally?

Comment: Added to the question a sample app (not mine)  and two sample documents.

Comment: What version of VS is it? I could not open the project.

Comment: I am using VS2011 beta (and I think the original example of the link too). I will try to convert it to vs2010 and add to the directory

Comment: Uploaded small modified project for Vs2010 at same link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sw9foaca1skkl5r/M5Q7BJwGxw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this discussion](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/354215), it should be fixed in the next drop of ASP.NET Web API:

> We have looked into this and while it does repro using the beta bits we have confirmed that the issue has been resolved in the latest bits. You can either try out the latest nightly build (see [instructions here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/29/using-nightly-nuget-packages-with-asp-net-web-stack.aspx)) or wait for our next drop.