# Microsoft Web API: How do you do a Server.MapPath?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Since *Microsoft Web API* isn't *MVC*, you cannot do something like this:

```cs
var a = Request.MapPath("~");
```

nor this

```cs
var b = Server.MapPath("~");
```

because these are under the `System.Web` namespace, not the `System.Web.Http` namespace.

So how do you figure out the relative server path in *Web API* ?
  I used to do something like this in *MVC*:

```cs
var myFile = Request.MapPath("~/Content/pics/" + filename);
```

Which would give me the absolute path on disk:

```
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myWebFolder\Content\pics\mypic.jpg"
```

Answer (score 510, accepted):

You can use [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx) in any context where `System.Web` objects like `HttpContext.Current` are not available (e.g also from a static method).

```cs
var mappedPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/SomePath");
```

See also [What is the difference between Server.MapPath and HostingEnvironment.MapPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944219/what-is-the-difference-between-server-mappath-and-hostingenvironment-mappath)

Comment: This is nice, but there's no easy way to mock HostingEnvironment since it is a static class instance... :-(

Comment: Sure, but in your controller or other logic layer that you want to test, you would take only a dependency on your own abstraction, like `IPathMapper` (you'll probably roll this up with a bunch of other concerns into a bigger toolbelt / utility interface) with the method `string MapPath(string virtualPath)`. Only the concrete implementation for your `WebApi IPathMapper` needs to know about `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment`

Comment: @JoshG -  you can abstract HostingEnvironment.MapPath via Func<string,string> GetWebPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath and then overwrite GetWebPath at test time with a mock.

Comment: looks like this is having trouble with relative paths like `../images/`

Comment: Its giving the controller path, so can I get the service path by using the "HostingEnvironment"?

Answer (score 17):

```cs
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
```

Comment: You don't want to use HttpContext.Current in WebAPI.  What about self-hosted APIs?  You cannot rely in HttpContext.Current to be there.  Also it is not test friendly.

Comment: It is not test-friendly that's correct. But in self-hosted apps there is still HttpContext ;)

Answer (score 2):

As an aside to those that stumble along across this, one nice way to run test level on using the HostingEnvironment call, is if accessing say a UNC share: \example\ that is mapped to ~/example/ you could execute this to get around IIS-Express issues:

```cs
#if DEBUG
    var fs = new FileStream(@"\\example\file",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
#else
    var fs = new FileStream(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/example/file"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
#endif
```

I find that helpful in case you have rights to locally test on a file, but need the env mapping once in production.

Comment: Fyi, the `HostingEnvironment` class is in the `System.Web.Hosting` namespace.

Comment: What is the alternative to `HostingEnvironment ` for DNX core 5.0?

Comment: The new Startup.cs class now Injects an 
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env){}
on construction, the property slips my mind, just did this the other day.

that allows you to also control an environment per instance, and using #if directives build an app that can cross tier deploy easily in multiple environments.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from the context you supply, but if it's something you just need to do at app startup, you can still use `Server.MapPath` in `WebApiHttpApplication`; e.g. in `Application_Start()`.

I'm just answering your direct question; the already-mentioned `HostingEnvironment.MapPath()` is probably the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Server.MapPath()` does not exist within a Web Api (Soap or REST), you'll need to denote the local- relative to the web server's context- home directory.  The easiest way to do so is with:

```
string AppContext.BaseDirectory { get;}
```

You can then use this to concatenate a path string to map the relative path to any file.
NOTE: string paths are `\` and not `/` like they are in mvc.

Ex:

```
System.IO.File.Exists($"{**AppContext.BaseDirectory**}\\\\Content\\\\pics\\\\{filename}");
```

returns true- positing that this is a sound path in your example

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late answering that but there we go.

I could solve this using Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: Could you add a bit more context on what your solution brings compared to the others and an example on how you would implement it ?

Answer (score -1):

The selected answer did not work in my Web API application. I had to use

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath
```

Comment: Although it seems this is the only way you can get path to your WebApi app, this gives you root of your application but doesn't translate relative paths such as `~\folder` or `../images/` to physical paths

Answer (score -2):

**You can try like:**

var path="~/Image/test.png";
    System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath( @ + path)