# Webapi2 project text file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a file called `template.html` in my project, set to Copy Always. When I run the api locally, from Visual Studio and do `File.ReadAllText("template.html")` I get `Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\template.html'.` Obviously, I could add an absolute path here, but that's not exactly portable. How can I access my file with a relative path?

Edit: my code is [here](https://github.com/DariusL/LocalPefChartinator). LocalPefChartinator is the main logic + CLI, Test is tests and WebInterface is the webapi bits.

Comment: Can't you embed it instead of copying it?

Comment: Yeah, a string would work instead of a file, but a file was easier to work with. I have a CLI version of this app and it copies the file to the build dir.

Comment: Where is `template.html` actually located in your solution?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer solution root folder

Comment: @DariusL Well, do you mean project root?

Comment: @DariusL Probably, your file is copied to `Bin\template.html`

Comment: @DariusL I meant to embed whole file, not string only.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yes, project root. I'll add a link to the repo.

Comment: Well, actually if you host your WebAPI on IIS you don't need copy always

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557122/microsoft-web-api-how-do-you-do-a-server-mappath

Comment: `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` worked. I'll check if it works when I publish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post linked by @MatíasFidemraizer helped.

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/template.html")
```

gives me an absolute path directly to my source if I run from Visual Studio. No idea what happens when I run it on AppHarbor, but it works.