# How to get physical file path in WEB API 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I need to get the physical path of a file in a controller based on Web API.

I have seen that I can use

```
var context = Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContext;
```

to get the context and then, by mean of the Server object, to use MapPath... however, MS_HttpContext is of type System.Web.HttpContextWrapper and when I cast to HttpContext, null is assigned to the variable.

Any hint about how to do this?

Regards
Jaime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft Web API: How do you do a Server.MapPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557122/microsoft-web-api-how-do-you-do-a-server-mappath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have used System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath method call.