# error writing mime multipart body part to output stream while uploading image files

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, webapi2

I am following this link to upload files from mvc view to server using webapi2

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/

but I am getting this error every time

"error writing mime multipart body part to output stream"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know issue. I was able to fix my problem with this solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17290999/321016

Comment: I want to know, how did you fixed this issue? Because i am also facing same problem. If you help me, that will be great

Comment: I made the changes suggested in the above stackoverflow link and it fixed my issue.